# Errors while deploying a JSF application on glassfish

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish

I am getting the following errors while trying to run my jsf application on glassfish server through netbeans6.9.

From Mozilla firefox:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type: Exception report

message:

description: The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception:    javax.servlet.ServletException: PWC1243: Filter execution threw an exception

root cause:    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory

root cause:    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory
```

Glassfish output as follows:

```
    Welcome to Felix
    ================
    INFO: Perform lazy SSL initialization for the listener 'http-listener-2'
    INFO: Starting Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-o - Fri Jun 24 23:30:29 IST 2011
    INFO: Starting Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-o - Fri Jun 24 23:30:29 IST 2011
    INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-o started in: 842ms listening on port 4848
    INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-o started in: 795ms listening on port 3700
    INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-o started in: 920ms listening on port 8080
    INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-o started in: 858ms listening on port 8181
    INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-o started in: 748ms listening on port 7676
    INFO: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.0.1 (22) startup time : Felix(22511ms) startup services(3244ms) total(25755ms)
    INFO: Binding RMI port to *:8686
    INFO: Hibernate Validator bean-validator-3.0-JBoss-4.0.2
    INFO: JMXStartupService: Started JMXConnector, JMXService URL = service:jmx:rmi://192.168.1.3:8686/jndi/rmi://192.168.1.3:8686/jmxrmi
    INFO: Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
    INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-o started in: 16ms listening on port 8080
    INFO: Using com.sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate as the delegate
    INFO: [Thread[GlassFish Kernel Main Thread,5,main]] started
    INFO: Perform lazy SSL initialization for the listener 'http-listener-2'
    INFO: {felix.fileinstall.poll (ms) = 5000, felix.fileinstall.dir = C:\Users\Rajat\.netbeans\6.9\config\GF3\domain1\autodeploy\bundles, felix.fileinstall.debug = 1, felix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start = true, felix.fileinstall.tmpdir = C:\Users\Rajat\AppData\Local\Temp\fileinstall--7360438857828003896, felix.fileinstall.filter = null}
    INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-o started in: 47ms listening on port 8181
    INFO: {felix.fileinstall.poll (ms) = 5000, felix.fileinstall.dir = C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfish\modules\autostart, felix.fileinstall.debug = 1, felix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start = true, felix.fileinstall.tmpdir = C:\Users\Rajat\AppData\Local\Temp\fileinstall--8677560274950500254, felix.fileinstall.filter = null}
    INFO: SEC1002: Security Manager is OFF.
    INFO: Security startup service called
    INFO: SEC1143: Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
    INFO: Realm admin-realm of classtype com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm successfully created.
    INFO: Realm file of classtype com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm successfully created.
    INFO: Realm certificate of classtype com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm successfully created.
    INFO: Security service(s) started successfully....
    INFO: Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on port 8080
    INFO: Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on port 8181
    INFO: Created HTTP listener admin-listener on port 4848
    INFO: Created virtual server server
    INFO: Created virtual server __asadmin
    INFO: Updating configuration from org.apache.felix.fileinstall-autodeploy-bundles.cfg
    INFO: Installed C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfish\modules\autostart\org.apache.felix.fileinstall-autodeploy-bundles.cfg
    INFO: {felix.fileinstall.poll (ms) = 5000, felix.fileinstall.dir = C:\Users\Rajat\.netbeans\6.9\config\GF3\domain1\autodeploy\bundles, felix.fileinstall.debug = 1, felix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start = true, felix.fileinstall.tmpdir = C:\Users\Rajat\AppData\Local\Temp\fileinstall--3915594108307422560, felix.fileinstall.filter = null}
    INFO: Virtual server server loaded system default web module
    INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.0.2 (FCS b10) for context '/Px10App'
    INFO: Running on PrimeFaces 3.0.M1
    INFO: Loading application Px10App at /Px10App
    INFO: Px10App was successfully deployed in 19,578 milliseconds.
    WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1657)
            at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.createManagedObject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:301)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.createFilterInstance(WebContainer.java:725)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.createFilterInstance(WebModule.java:1948)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:248)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:237)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:277)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
            at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
            at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
            at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
            at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
            at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
            at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
            at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
            at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
            at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:959)
            at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1430)
            ... 33 more

    WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1657)
            at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.createManagedObject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:301)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.createFilterInstance(WebContainer.java:725)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.createFilterInstance(WebModule.java:1948)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:248)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:237)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:277)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
            at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
            at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
            at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
            at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
            at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
            at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
            at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
            at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
            at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:959)
            at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1430)
            ... 33 more

    WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1657)
            at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.createManagedObject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:301)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.createFilterInstance(WebContainer.java:725)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.createFilterInstance(WebModule.java:1948)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:248)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:237)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:277)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
            at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
            at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
            at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
            at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
            at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
            at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
            at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
            at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
            at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:959)
            at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1430)
            ... 33 more
```

How can I succesfully run the application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the exception it is very evident that certain classes required by the application were not loaded by the class loader because their defintions (.class files) were absent.

This is usually because the classes are simply unavailable in the application server (like the EJB APIs on Tomcat 6) or you missed packaging a particular dependency (in this case, the Apache Commons FileUpload library). You'll need to ensure that your EAR/WAR file contains this dependency in a location (usually WEB-INF/lib of the WAR file, or /lib directory of the EAR file) to enable the classloader to locate the necessary classes at runtime.

In Netbeans, you will typically not need to do anything to ensure this. My opinion is that the 'package' checkbox (see the screenshot below) has been unchecked for the Apache Commons FileUpload library (or jar file), and therefore Netbeans will no longer package this into the WAR/EAR file. Do not forget to clean and rebuild you project.

[image: Netbeans package library JAR option]

You can also do this, in the packaging properties of the project, in case you do not wish to add the library to the project (for some unknown reason). You'll need to explicitly specify the path within the WAR file as "WEB-INF/lib".

[image: Package library into WAR]

Comment: when I create a new java web project it runs perfect but when I copy my source files to this project, it starts giving out this error. Previously in my old project I was never required to speciofy any such library even. As of now, I could not see your specified library anywhere in my classpath

Comment: @Raj, failures do not occur magically and for no reason. There must be something specific to your older project that prevented this scenario. Perhaps you might want to study the WAR/EAR file of the older project (maybe a clean and rebuild of the old project will cause the same issue), or maybe even it's build.xml files. Also, the file in the screenshot is one that I've added from my repository of JAR files.